# Postfix SMTP only localhost login - disable remote login

Tags: postfix, localhost, rules

I have configured postfix + dovecot on a debain 10.
I have installed a web server to have webmail with roundcube.

I don't want anyone other than roundcube to be able to use mail services, so I'm only exposing SMTP ports 25 and 587 to the internet.

How can I configure Postfix to not allow login attempts from the internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the SMTP port 25 for unauthenticated incoming mail and configure the *submission* port 587 separately for (outbound) authenticated mail, you could make it only listen on local loopback.

In the `master.cf` you have a separate section, another instance of `smtpd` for the submission:

```
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
```

You could modify this line into:

```
127.0.0.1:submission inet n -   y       -       -       smtpd
```

(According to [master(5)](http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html) it seems `inet_interfaces = loopback-only` is only available on the `main.cf`. This would mean you can only configure it globally and not per process with `-o` in `master.cf`.)

Comment: In the end I have done what you say, submission in local and smtp on the internet with 'smtp_sasl_auth_enable = no'.
What seems strange to me is that there is no configuration of smtpd itself to disable remote authentication.